Use wildcards to trace an a.href in the querySelectorAll NodeList
Let's say that instead of looking at the ID, I want to select all a.href elements that contain (a piece of) this example: if document.url is "www.youtube.com".
var youtubeID = document.querySelectorAll('.youtubelink');

var youtubeDiv = document.querySelectorAll('a[href^="http://www.youtube.com"]');


use * wildcard instead ^ which matches only the stating of the string

You can use * wildcard which matches any attribute value where https://www.youtube.com appears anywhere in the string.
Use this selector
a[href*="https://www.youtube.com"]


var youtubeDiv = document.querySelectorAll('a[href*="https://www.youtube.com"]');
console.log(youtubeDiv.length);
<a href="https://www.youtube.com/example-slug">Link 1</a>
<a href="https://example.com?link=https://www.youtube.com/example-slug">Link 2</a>
<a href="https://example.com?link=https://www.youtube.com/example-slug&referer=stack">Link 3</a>




The most fast and easy way is to use the [attribute*=value] selector:


document.querySelectorAll('a[href*="www.youtube.com"]')
  .forEach(link => console.log(link.href));

setTimeout(markYouTubeContainingLinks, 1500);

function markYouTubeContainingLinks() {
  // there is no [attribute!="..."] selector, so
  // if you look for hrefs not containing "..." 
  // you have to visit all links in a loop
  document.querySelectorAll('a')
  .forEach(link => {
    if (!/www\.youtube\.com/i.test(link.href)) {
      link.style.color = `#c0c0c0`;
      return;
    }

    link.style.color = `green`;
    link.style.fontWeight = `bold`;
  });
}
a { text-decoration: none }
<a href="https://hello.com?url=www.youtube.com/any">YT 1</a><br>
<a href="https://somelink.somewhere.com?link=https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6RxqNv6bEug&ab_channel=LastWeekTonight">YT 2</a><br>
<a href="https://notyoutube.com">NOT YT</a><br>
<a href="https://www.youtube.com/something">YT 3</a><br>
<a href="https://www.google.com/">NOT YT</a><br>




@YuvarajM's example selects the given link even if it contains only part of url (example: anothersite.com?link=www.example.com). Additionally, it will not select it if it is written with the http:// protocol instead of https://, or if the www. part is not included.
Although this solution is correct, you may want to set stricter rules, which, however, is not possible using querySelector.
Solution
Using regex allows for even more unique and stringent rules to be specified.
With my example, it will select all your hyperlinks regardless of the protocol and www., which are:

example.com (without protocol and www.)
www.example.com (without protocol)
http://example.com (without www.)
http://www.example.com
https://example.com (without www., with a different protocol)
https://www.example.com



// Select <a> elements with hrefs containing the pattern
function selectExampleComLinks() {
  const links = document.querySelectorAll('a');
  const pattern = /^(https?:)?\/\/(www\.)?example\.com/; // pattern that the URL must match
  return Array.from(links).filter(link => pattern.test(link.href)); // from the <a> array, we filter out those where the result of pattern.test() will be true 
}

// Test
const matchingLinks = selectExampleComLinks();
console.log(matchingLinks);
a {
  display: block;
}
<!-- Successfully cases -->
<a href="//example.com">example.com (without protocoll, without www)</a>
<a href="//www.example.com">www.example.com (without protocoll)</a>
<a href="http://example.com">example.com (HTTP, without www)</a>
<a href="http://www.example.com">www.example.com (HTTP)</a>
<a href="https://example.com">example.com (HTTPS, without www)</a>
<a href="https://www.example.com">www.example.com (HTTPS)</a>
<a href="https://www.example.com/slug">www.example.com/slug (with slug)</a>
<a href="https://www.example.com/slug/">www.example.com/slug/ (end of /)</a>
<a href="https://www.example.com?example=query">www.example.com?example=query (with query)</a>

<!-- Test cases -->
<a href="//nonexample.com">nonexample.com</a>
<a href="//www.nonexample.com">www.nonexample.com</a>
<a href="http://nonexample.com">http://nonexample.com</a>
<a href="http://www.nonexample.com">http://www.nonexample.com</a>
<a href="https://nonexample.com">https://nonexample.com</a>
<a href="https://www.nonexample.com">https://www.nonexample.com</a>
<a href="//nonexample.com?link=http://www.example.com">nonexample.com (example.com just a part of this url)</a>
<a href="//subdomain.example.com'">subdomain.example.com (this just a subdomain of example.com)</a>



More information

Document: querySelectorAll() method - MDN Docs
Regular expressions - MDN Docs
Array.from() - MDN Docs
Array.prototype.filter() - MDN Docs


If all you want is to get links to a specific host, the following will suffice:
function* filter_by_host(links, host) {
    for(const link of links) {
        if(link.host == host) yield link;
    }
}

It can be used like so:
for(const youtube_link of filter_by_host(document.links, "www.youtube.com")) {
    /// Use `youtube_link`...
}

Or you can just turn the results into an array, for convenience:
const youtube_links = Array.from(filter_by_host(document.links))

If filter is what you'd rather use, either one of the following two alternatives to filter_by_host, can also be used:
const youtube_links = Array.prototype.filter.call(document.links, link => link.host == "www.youtube.com");

const youtube_links = Array.from(document.links).filter(link => link.host == "www.youtube.com");

Depending on how Array.prototype.filter is implemented, the former can be faster but the latter is arguably more "traditional".
If you need more filtering of the link -- for example, on the scheme ("https:"), you can use other attributes of HTMLAnchorElement.
I think using either of querySelectorAll or regular expressions in your case, is entirely unnecessary, given how the user agent has already ostensibly parsed every link's reference through properties like host etc. At least it makes these conveniently available without your needing to assemble regular expression patterns and have the user agent parse CSS selectors even if it's "*".
